# Generate status report for servers on different domain using Power shell

Tags: powershell, cross-domain

I am trying to generate server status HTML report for list of servers mentioned in text file. Some of my servers are in different domains so it gives me error.

**Error** :

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\Users\raj.negi.RESONATE\Desktop\WinServ-Status.ps1:143 char:32
+             $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ...
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

It is working fine for the servers which is in same domain from where i running the script.
[image]

I am able to ping successfully the other domain server.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    $ServerFile = "C:\ServerStatus\ServerList.txt",
    $OutputPath = "C:\ServerStatus",
    [alias("DiskAlert")]
    $DiskAlertThreshold,
    [alias("CpuAlert")]
    $CpuAlertThreshold,
    [alias("MemAlert")]
    $MemAlertThreshold,
    [alias("Refresh")]
    $RefreshTime,
    [alias("SendTo")]
    $MailTo,
    [alias("From")]
    $MailFrom,
    [alias("Smtp")]
    $SmtpServer,
    [alias("User")]
    $SmtpUser,
    [alias("Pwd")]
    $SmtpPwd,
    [switch]$UseSsl)

## Function to get the up time from the server
Function Get-UpTime
{
    param([string] $LastBootTime)
    $Uptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootTime)
    "$($Uptime.Days) days $($Uptime.Hours)h $($Uptime.Minutes)m"
}

## Begining of the loop. Lower down the loop is broken if the refresh option is not configured.
Do
{
    ## Change value of the following parameter as needed
    $OutputFile = "$OutputPath\WinServ-Status-Report.htm"
    $ServerList = Get-Content $ServerFile
    $Result = @()

    ## Look through the servers in the file provided
    ForEach ($ServerName in $ServerList)
    {
        $PingStatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ServerName -Count 1 -Quiet

        ## If server responds, get uptime and disk info
        If ($PingStatus)
        {
            $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ServerName
            $CpuAlert = $false
            $CpuUsage = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -Computername $ServerName | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | ForEach-Object {$_.Average; If($_.Average -ge $CpuAlertThreshold){$CpuAlert = $True}; "%"}
            $Uptime = Get-Uptime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)
            $MemAlert = $false
            $MemUsage = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ServerName | ForEach-Object {“{0:N0}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory) * 100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize); If((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory) * 100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize -ge $MemAlertThreshold){$MemAlert = $True}; "%"}
            $DiskAlert = $false
            $DiskUsage = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ServerName | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} | Foreach-Object {$_.DeviceID, [Math]::Round((($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace) * 100)/ $_.Size); If([Math]::Round((($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace) * 100)/ $_.Size) -ge $DiskAlertThreshold){$DiskAlert = $True}; "%"}
            $IPv4Address = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $ServerName | Select-Object -Expand IPAddress | Where-Object { ([Net.IPAddress]$_).AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork" }
        }

        ## Put the results together
        $Result += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            ServerName = $ServerName
            IPV4Address = $IPv4Address
            Status = $PingStatus
            CpuUsage = $CpuUsage
            CpuAlert = $CpuAlert
            Uptime = $Uptime
            MemUsage = $MemUsage
            MemAlert = $MemAlert
            DiskUsage = $DiskUsage
            DiskAlert = $DiskAlert
        }

        ## Clear the variables after obtaining and storing the results so offline servers don't have duplicate info.
        Clear-Variable IPv4Address
        Clear-Variable Uptime
        Clear-Variable MemUsage
        Clear-Variable CpuUsage
        Clear-Variable DiskUsage
    }

    ## If there is a result put the HTML file together.
    If ($Result -ne $null)
    {
        $HTML = '<style type="text/css">
                p {font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px}
                p {color:#ffffff;}
                #Header{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
                #Header td, #Header th {font-size:15px;text-align:left;border:1px solid #1a1a1a;padding:2px 2px 2px 7px;color:#ffffff;}
                #Header th {font-size:16px;text-align:center;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#4B4B4B;color:#ffffff;}
                #Header tr.alt td {color:#ffffff;background-color:#eaf2d3;}
                #Header tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#4B4B4B;}
                #Header tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#4B4B4B;}
                body {background-color: #1a1a1a;}
                </style>
                <head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"></head>'

        $HTML += "<html><body>
            <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 id=header>
            <tr>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>Server</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>IP</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>Status</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>CPU Usage</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>Memory Usage</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>Disk Usage</font></b></th>
                <th><b><font color=#e6e6e6>Uptime</font></b></th>
            </tr>"

        ## Highlight the alerts if the alerts are triggered.
        ForEach($Entry in $Result)
        {
            If ($Entry.Status -eq $True)
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>$($Entry.ServerName)</font></td>"
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 $($Entry.ServerName)</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.Status -eq $True)
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>$($Entry.IPV4Address)</font></td>"
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.Status -eq $True)
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>&#10004 Online</font></td>"
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.CpuUsage -ne $null)
            {
                If ($Entry.CpuAlert -eq $True)
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#ffff4d>&#9888 $($Entry.CpuUsage)</font></td>"
                }

                Else
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>&#10004 $($Entry.CpuUsage)</font></td>"
                }
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.MemUsage -ne $null)
            {
                If ($Entry.MemAlert -eq $True)
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#ffff4d>&#9888 $($Entry.MemUsage)</font></td>"
                }

                Else
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>&#10004 $($Entry.MemUsage)</font></td>"
                }
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.DiskUsage -ne $null)
            {
                If ($Entry.DiskAlert -eq $True)
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#ffff4d>&#9888 $($Entry.DiskUsage)</font></td>"
                }

                Else
                {
                    $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>&#10004 $($Entry.DiskUsage)</font></td>"
                }
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>"
            }

            If ($Entry.Status -eq $True)
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#00e600>$($Entry.Uptime)</font></td>
                          </tr>"
            }

            Else
            {
                $HTML += "<td><font color=#FF4D4D>&#10008 Offline</font></td>
                          </tr>"
            }
        }

        ## Report the date and time the script ran.
        $HTML += "</table><p><font color=#e6e6e6>Status refreshed on: $(Get-Date -Format G)</font></p></body></html>"

        ## Output the HTML file
        $HTML | Out-File $OutputFile

        ## If email was configured, set the variables for the email subject and body
        If ($SmtpServer)
        {
            $MailSubject = "Server Status Report"
            $MailBody = Get-Content -Path $OutputFile | Out-String

            ## If an email password was configured, create a variable with the username and password
            If ($SmtpPwd)
            {
                $SmtpPwdEncrypt = Get-Content $SmtpPwd | ConvertTo-SecureString
                $SmtpCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($SmtpUser, $SmtpPwdEncrypt)

                ## If ssl was configured, send the email with ssl
                If ($UseSsl)
                {
                    Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -UseSsl -Credential $SmtpCreds
                }

                ## If ssl wasn't configured, send the email without ssl
                Else
                {
                    Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Credential $SmtpCreds
                }
            }

            ## If an email username and password were not configured, send the email without authentication
            Else
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo -From $MailFrom -Subject $MailSubject -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SmtpServer
            }
        }

        ## If the refresh time option is configured, wait the specifed number of seconds then loop.
        If ($RefreshTime -ne $null)
        {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $RefreshTime
        }
    }
}

## If the refresh time option is not configured, stop the loop.
Until ($RefreshTime -eq $null)
```

**Firewall is Off on all servers.**

Comment: First off, that a really nice script output. But the issue with your script is one of two things. A. I don't see anywhere where you are sending credentials so its using your current logged in user credentials which most likely doesn't have admin access to the computers on the other domain. OR it could be there is a firewall or service that is blocking your connections.

Comment: Yes i think (A) should be the reason. But how can i manage different domains at the same time.

Comment: Move the part of the script that reaches out to remote computers to a seperate function and add input variables so you can pass credentials to the function, then just call the function in your script loop instead of having it as a main part of the script. Basicly the entire section of the "If ($PingStatus)" needs to be moved into a function. That being said, once you do that I would love it if I could get a copy of the script and permission to use it.

Comment: Suppose If i use credential in the script then only server which having the credential will success and others will fail. My single credential is not present in all the domains. I have different credential in each domain.

Comment: thats why you add it to a function. You can add a seperate list in the server files to list what credentials to use for each server. When I get home from work i'll play with this script and see what I can figure out if you havn't by then.

Comment: ohk got it. Update script once done.